# How to mask an image faster in IOS?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am using this code for mask a gradient with an image. But it is very slow.

```
CGImageRef gradientMaskImage = CreateGradientImage(1, 500);
CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([[UIImage imageNamed:@"brooklyn_new.jpg"] CGImage], gradientMaskImage);

UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
CGImageRelease(gradientMaskImage);
CGImageRelease(masked);
return result;
```

And for CreateGradientImage:

```
CGImageRef CreateGradientImage(int pixelsWide, int pixelsHigh)
{
CGImageRef theCGImage = NULL;

// gradient is always black-white and the mask must be in the gray colorspace
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

// create the bitmap context
CGContextRef gradientBitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh,
                                                           8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);

// define the start and end grayscale values (with the alpha, even though
// our bitmap context doesn't support alpha the gradient requires it)
CGFloat colors[] = {0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

// create the CGGradient and then release the gray color space
CGGradientRef grayScaleGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

// create the start and end points for the gradient vector (straight down)
CGPoint gradientStartPoint = CGPointZero;
CGPoint gradientEndPoint = CGPointMake(0, pixelsHigh);

// draw the gradient into the gray bitmap context
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(gradientBitmapContext, grayScaleGradient, gradientStartPoint,
                            gradientEndPoint, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
CGGradientRelease(grayScaleGradient);

// convert the context into a CGImageRef and release the context
theCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(gradientBitmapContext);
CGContextRelease(gradientBitmapContext);

// return the imageref containing the gradient
return theCGImage;
}
```

////

```
CGImageRef gradientMaskImage = CreateGradientImage(1, 500);
```

Here 500 will be a variable. So anytime I call this function with a variable height, it will redraw an masked image. So It should be very very fast.

How can I do it faster?

Comment: No, can you give more information?

Comment: Is it related with Transition effects like http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH203-BAJGIDBF ? If yes, how I can do the transition giving some input?

Comment: And CIImageAccumulator can be the answer?